# Angular: select ng-model programmatically changed but ng-change event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

Here's my select element:

```
 <select class="small-3 columns end statSelect"
          ng-model="chart.categoryAxis"
          ng-change="renderMainChart()"
          ng-options="metric as metric.value for metric in chart.metrics()">
  </select>
```

I'm changing chart.categoryAxis programmatically every time I click on a button. However, the ng-change method renderMainChart() doesn't get called. Why is this?

Here's an example of one of the options:

`<option label="Ad Started" value="object:33">Ad Started</option>`

Depending on which button I click, that changes the ng-model value appropriately. But the ng-change function renderMainChart() doesn't get called.

Comment: `ng-change` is an event handler for the `<select>` element. Sounds like you're more after a *watch* on `chart.categoryAxis`

Answer (score 2):

Aelliott1485's answer can be implemented but it would need you to add an extra watch which may not be preferable always.

---

If you are using Angular 1.3 or higher then you can pass a function to the `ng-model` directive.

This allows you to specify a method instead of a variable in your `ng-model` attribute. The method should take an optional parameter. If an argument is passed it should store that value, if no argument is passed it should return a value.

In this case change your ng-model to call a function instead of accessing a property.

```
<select class="small-3 columns end statSelect"
      ng-model="chart.categoryAxis()"
      ng-change="renderMainChart()"
      ng-options="metric as metric.value for metric in chart.metrics()">    
</select>
```

and write a function like this in your controller

```
$scope.categoryAxis = function(value) {
    $scope.ca = value || $scope.ca; // You can also keep a local variable inside the controller instead of a property on $scope
    return $scope.ca;
};
```

NOTE: You may need to come up with better names.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [$watch()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) to handle the changing of the value, even when the user doesn't change the value using the select list. For example:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var options = [{
    value: 'a',
    id: 1
  }, {
    value: 'b',
    id: 2
  }];
  $scope.debugOutput = '';
  $scope.chart = {
    categoryAxis: options[0],
    metrics: function() {
      return options;
    }
  };
  $scope.renderMainChart = function() {
    console.log('renderMainChart', arguments);
  };
  $scope.pickA = function() {
    $scope.chart.categoryAxis = options[0];
  };
  $scope.pickB = function() {
    $scope.chart.categoryAxis = options[1];
  };
  $scope.$watch('chart.categoryAxis', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.debugOutput += 'categoryAxis changed ' + angular.toJson(oldValue) + ' to ' + angular.toJson(newValue) + "\n";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select class="small-3 columns end statSelect" ng-model="chart.categoryAxis" ng-change="renderMainChart()" ng-options="metric as metric.value for metric in chart.metrics()"></select>
    <div>Selected category Axis:
    <span>{{ chart.categoryAxis | json }}</span></div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" ng-click="pickA()" value="pickA" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" ng-click="pickB()" value="pickB" />
    </div>
    <div>{{ debugOutput }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```